# can I use logrotate to rotate /core files?

Tags: linux, logrotate

On remote linux-based devices, I thought I'd use logrotate to manage any core files our appliance may create.  But it seems logrotate considers every core file a unique file since the filename includes the PID.  This breaks the way logrotate normally rotates files.  E.g.:

```
core_123
core_222
core_555
```

Instead of seeing these as 3 variations of the same file, it sees this as 3 unique files.  So if I had `rotate 50` in `/etc/logrotate.d/core`, it would be willing to rotate through 50 different `core_123` files, and 50 different `core_222` files, etc., resulting in potentially hundreds or thousands of files.  Instead, I want to ensure that logrotate manages a maximum of 50 core_* files.

This is the exact logrotate file I was trying to make work:

```
/mycores/core_* {
    compress
    daily
    maxage 28
    missingok
    nocreate
    nodelaycompress
    olddir /mycores/old
    rotate 50
}
```

I suspect this isn't possible with logrotate, but I figured I'd post on serverfault just in case I missed something in the documentation.

Comment: Why are you generating core files in the first place?

Comment: That's a question for Stackoverflow.  Since we have lots of software running on these devices and cannot control when something wrong is going to happen, we at least need to manage the cores (should they happen) so they don't eat up all the disk space.  We do want to keep some recent cores to help us in debugging issues as they come up.

Comment: It might be easier to use something like find with a -mtime option to just delete things older then some time period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined `logrotate` with some shell magic to get the desired effect.  Basically logrotate is still in charge of moving and compressing the files, and then kicking off the script needed to delete the old files as well as ensuring the directory doesn't have more than 50 or so files.  Here is what I did:

```
/mycores/core_* {
    compress
    daily
    missingok
    nocreate
    nodelaycompress
    olddir /mycores/old
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        # delete all core_*.gz files older than 28 days
        find /mycores/old -name "core_*.gz" -mtime +28 -delete
        # make sure we have a max of 50 files; delete the oldest files if we have too many
        for filename in $(find /mycores/old/ -name "core_*.gz" -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort --reverse | tail --lines=+51 | cut -d' ' -f2); do rm $filename; sleep 0.5; done
    endscript
}
```

I'm not the best bash scripter out there, so that `postrotate` script section might be heavier than necessary...  :)

Answer (score 2):

We use a script like this. I don't see the point of involving logrotate as

1. these are not log files
2. you are not rotating them

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
EMAIL_TO="<%= mail %>"
EMAIL_SUBJ="Found core files on `hostname -s`"
DATETIME=`date +"%F-%H%M%S"`
EMPTY_CORE_FILES=`find /var/log/core/ -mmin +60 -type f -empty -not -name "*.gz" -not -name "*.zip" -print -exec rm {} \;`
CORE_FILES=`find /var/log/core/ -mmin +60 -type f -not -empty -not -name "*.gz" -not -name "*.zip"`
NUM_CORE_FILES=`echo $CORE_FILES | wc -w`

lockfile="/tmp/`basename $0`.lock"
lockfile -1 -r 5 -l 84600 ${lockfile} || exit 1
trap "/bin/rm -f $lockfile" EXIT INT TERM

for f in $CORE_FILES;
do
  gzip -9 $f
done

if [ $NUM_CORE_FILES != 0 ]
then

  mail "$EMAIL_TO" -s "$EMAIL_SUBJ" <<EOF
I found and gzipped $NUM_CORE_FILES on $HOSTNAME in /var/log/core, please investigate.

Files Found:
$CORE_FILES

Empty Files:
$EMPTY_CORE_FILES

EOF

fi
```